# EXCEL formula calculating the sum of a column for the last 7 days from today as a reference?

Tags: excel-formula

Have searched the database but need to specifically sum(of hours flown or days off)in a column for the last 7 days using today as a reference i.e.

column A      column B

06 JAN 12          0hours

07 JAN 12          1hours

08 JAN 12          1hours

09 JAN 12          1hours

10 JAN 12          0hours

11 JAN 12          0hours

12 JAN 12          1hours

TODAY              1hours

13 JAN 12          1hours

14 JAN 12          1hours

Anyone can help will be appreciated -thanks

p.s I amended the above data for better clarification

DATE    DAILY HOURS TOTAL HRS FLOWN IN LAST 7 DAYS

A               B        C

6/Jan/12    1.0 8.0

7/Jan/12    1.0

8/Jan/12    1.0

9/Jan/12    1.0

10/Jan/12   1.0

11/Jan/12   1.0

12/Jan/12   1.0

13/Jan/12   1.0

14/Jan/12   1.0

15/Jan/12   1.0

16/Jan/12   1.0

17/Jan/12

18/Jan/12

19/Jan/12

20/Jan/12

21/Jan/12

Hi Robert and Barry, thanks for your responses and patience to this 'newbie' in Excel.I have copied the latest format for your consideration. Currently the date column(A) is conditionally formatted to be highlighted when it is "today".The daily hours column(B) is formatted for # and the formula for the Total for last 7days(column C) is =SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&TODAY()-7,B:B,"<="&TODAY()).

Currently the formula calculates the hours from today(C12:C5),and funny if I add input after the todays date it adds it the total too!!I basically need it to calculate the hours flown for the last 7 days not including any hours flown for "today".

Other formulas I have tried are:
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$12:$A$64>$M$9),$C$12:$C$64) or
=SUM(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(99^99,B:B)):INDEX(B:B,MATCH(99^99,B:B)-6))

Comment: Do you actually have "TODAY" as an entry, rather than a date? Which 7 days are you summing - does that include today?

Comment: In this case, I would try to get rid of the "today" text, or I would "replicate" the dates in column C and automatically replace the text "today" with =today() to get today's numeric value. B.t.w. I assume that the 1 hour or 2 hour field is formatted as #" hour", so that the actual input in each cell is just a number, and no text.

Comment: One solution to "highlight" today, could be to use the date everywhere, but autoformat the column such that today's date shows up with a red or yellow background.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far I edited the question for your consideration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&TODAY()-7,A:A,"<="&TODAY())
```

Comment: Hi Robert,it kinda of works,however there is a problem with the SUMIFS or SUMPRODUCT formulas is that if you have dates  after  the "today" row in column A with corresponding number values it adds those to the calculation, as well as if there is any data next to the "today" row?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">"&TODAY()-7)-SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">"&TODAY())
```

Here you add everything that is larger than (today - 7) and subtract everything more than today.

Comment: Hi Robert, a question wrt to the above formula, is it possible to add a condition to it so that it retains the result of the formula for that day on that line,and when it rolls over onto the next day it will calculate the new result as per the formula and retain the result when it rolls over to the next day etc etc..Not sure if you understand ?

Comment: I think I do understand. I think that you want to have an extra column (e.g. C) where next to every date (col. A), you see the number of hours registered for today (Col. B) and in Column C you see the sum for the last 7 days. in that case replace TODAY() with the reference of the cell in Column A (e.g. A2 or A3). I'll test this and report back.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the formula's from one (random) row.

Cell A12:just has a date e.g. jan 11 2012

Cell B12:just has a number of hours e.g. 5

Cell C12: Shows total number of hours in last 7 days

=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&A12-6,A:A,"<="&A12)

Cell D12: Shows the date range

=TEXT(A12-6, "dd-mmm")&" till "&TEXT(A12, "dd-mmm")

I changed the formula and also reduced the -7 to -6 because it is today -6 which totals 7 days

Also make sure you have conditional formatting for column A:A set to equal to: =today() with your choice of colors.

[image]

Comment: What can I say-pure genius THANKS a mil!! I have a slight problem with conditional formatting one of the cells wrt to this formula? Should I start a new question or can I ask it here?